# Python: How can I count specific numbers of a list of lists without using .count?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
list = [["apple", "apple","bananas"], ["bananas, "apple", "bananas"], ["bananas","bananas","pear"]]
```

I want to know how many bananas do I have in each sub list. I want to obtain:

```
number = [1],[2],[2]
```

I would like to achieve this using loops and condicionals and the minimum number of fancy funtions. I don't want to use .count, but .append would be ok.

I have tried this:

```
number = []
for cart in list:
    for fruit in range (0,len(cart)):
        if cart[fruit] == "banana":
            number.append("banana")
print(len(number))
```

But this only gives me the total number of bananas, not a list of fruit per cart.

What could I do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[len(l) for l in list]`? (it's better having a different name than `list`).

Comment: "I don't want to use .count, but .append would be ok." What is the reason for this restriction? Is this a personal learning project or some exercise? Do you actually *have* to use ``append``?

Comment: Can you please make sure to [edit] your question to so that the code is correct and consistent? The ``list`` definition has a syntax error, and the example code will return 0 instead of the total number – it tests for ``"banana"`` but the cart only contains ``"bananas"``.

Comment: why would you want to obtain this: `[1],[2],[2]`? That seems pretty useless, how about [1, 2, 2,]`?

Comment: Would something like ``*number, = map(lambda cart: sum(map("bananas".__eq__, cart)), list)`` be sufficient for your requirements?

Comment: "What is the reason for this restriction? " The reason is that I am trying to learn how to use loops to count. "Do you actually have to use append?" No, don't have to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you would like to achieve this using a minimum number of fancy functions, I have coded it with just `list.append()` and loop nesting.

```
carts = [["apple", "apple", "bananas"], ["bananas", "apple", "bananas"], ["bananas","bananas","pear"]]

banana_counts = []

for cart in carts:  
  count = 0
  for fruit in cart: # Using range() here is not Pythonic
    if fruit == 'bananas':
      count += 1
  banana_counts.append([count])

print(banana_counts) #[[1], [2], [2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

2-level list comprehension with `sum()`

```
mylist = [["apple", "apple","bananas"], ["bananas", "apple", "bananas"], ["bananas","bananas","pear"]]
number = [[sum([1 if 'banana' in y else 0 for y in x])] for x in mylist]
print(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number = []
for c in range(len(carts)):
    n = 0
    for fruit in carts[c]:
        if fruit == "banana":
            n += 1
    number.append(n)

print(sum(number))
```

Comment: don't do `for c in range(len(carts))`. Just *iterate over the list directly: `for cart in carts: for fruit in cart: ...` But otherwise I think this is closest to the spirit of the question. Also I don't think the op wants `sum(number)`

Answer (score 0):

```
number = [len([j for j in i if j=='banana']) for i in your_list]
```

explanation:

```
[j for j in i if j=='banana'] # will result a list of only "banana"s from list "i" which is one element of source list
```

We create a list containing only "banana"s of each element in source list and then we get the length of these lists to get our desired result.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score -1):

`len([cart for cart in carts if 'banana' in cart])`